# digging into a signal

Tags: signal-analysis

I am a civil engineer and I have a research focused on InSAR Data.
I have a basic question about analyzing the signals, please.
How can I dig into the signal I have?
Is there any code to define the pattern of the signal or just by ploting the values along the points of time? or maybe there is a specific procedure I should follow.

I am very confused and it is very necessary for me to find an answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi! It's sadly not clear what you mean with "InSAR data". Do you mean a raw time signal? Or the despreaded signal? Or processed ground swath image data? Maybe a specific link to the specific data you have would help us.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcus.. I mean interferometric radar data...differential phase measurements

Comment: so, the time-domain phase measurements, or the already chirp-compressed phase measurements, or the processed ground swath phase image data?

Comment: It is processed ground swath phase image data

Comment: cool! So, you don't have to generate these images. So, what do you want to *do* with that? "Pattern of the signal": not quite sure what you mean with that; are you looking for some specific objects in that imagery?

Comment: I generated a dataset from these images.. the dataset is composed of sequenced pixels.. I have 2 different signals represented by this dataset, too.. what I want is to find a way to distinguish between the 2 signals... that is why I said to find a pattern .... I hope that I explained my idea well.. thanks a lot

Comment: really speaking in riddles. Please be more specific.

Comment: I am really sorry...I have 2 different signals stored in a matrix.. each row of the matrix represents one of these 2 signals.. I need to find a pattern for each signal to separate between them.. more clear?

Comment: knowing that each row of the matrix is a sequence of pixels from processed ground swath phase image data